# Is it ok to cite someone who provided a bad citation for correct information?

Tags: citations

In a master's thesis the author provided a seemingly incorrect citation. ( [Link to paper](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-01182002-134625/unrestricted/ThesisB.pdf) citation 4)

The information is obviously correct but in the cited paper I couldn't find any reference to the information he cited. Is it ok to cite him?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to refer to his work (i.e. his results, discussion or conclusions), you should cite it.

If you want a reference to the particular piece of information he cited (the sentences describing plasma etching before his call to ref. 4), then you should find a direct source: either a textbook or review on the topic. This would be much better than a research article (or thesis), especially one badly sourced.

Comment: Why would a research article be better than a review?  At least in my field, research articles tend to be _much_ more carefully refereed than surveys or textbooks.

Comment: What I meant is: if you want a reference for, e.g., how Smith’s formula applies to psychomechanics, you’d rather find a review article on that, or a textbook if it's a textbook matter, rather than citing a research paper chosen at random among the 100’s that use this formula.

Answer (score 2):

In general I do not like citing non-peer reviewed sources. Further, it sounds like you ware using it as a secondary source, which I like citing even less.